# How to get sql WHERE statement auto update from localhost link

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have my exam webpage develop in php code.

I wish to know that how to auto retrieve the WHERE value from the link.

For example my webpage link will be :

http://localhost/Exam/OES/OES/oes/admin/rsltmng.php?testid=4

When I click on another result for others test paper, the link will change to 
http://localhost/Exam/OES/OES/oes/admin/rsltmng.php?testid=3

I wish to know that how can I auto pass the testid value into my sql code.

Currently my sql code will look like this:
  //code formatting for your question.

```
 `$result3=executeQuery("SELECT x.stdid, x.testid, x.questionsInTest, x.questionsCorrect, ROUND( 100.0 * x.questionsCorrect / x.questionsInTest ) AS percentScore FROM ( SELECT s.stdid, q.testid, COUNT(q.qnid) AS questionsInTest, SUM( IF(s.answered='answered' AND s.stdanswer=q.correctanswer, 1, 0 ) ) AS questionsCorrect FROM question AS q INNER JOIN studentquestion AS s ON q.testid = s.testid AND q.qnid = s.qnid WHERE q.testid=".$_REQUEST['testid']." GROUP BY s.stdid, q.testid ) AS X ORDER BY x.stdid, x.testid;"); `
```

When I put in this code, there is no result being shown on my page.

====
As below will be the table that is involve.

question table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question` (
`testid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`qnid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`question` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`optiona` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`optionb` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`optionc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`optiond` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `correctanswer` enum('optiona','optionb','optionc','optiond') DEFAULT NULL,
`marks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

 --
 -- Dumping data for table `question`
  --

    INSERT INTO `question` (`testid`, `qnid`, `question`, `optiona`,   `optionb`, `optionc`, `optiond`, `correctanswer`, `marks`) VALUES
  (1, 1, 'question for test 1', 'ans1', 'ans 2', 'ans 3', 'ans 4', 'optiona', 1),
  (2, 1, 'question test', 'ans1', 'ans2', 'ans3', 'ans4', 'optiona', 1);
```

studentquestion table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `studentquestion` (
`stdid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`testid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`qnid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`answered` enum('answered','unanswered','review') DEFAULT NULL,
`stdanswer` enum('optiona','optionb','optionc','optiond') DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `studentquestion`
--

INSERT INTO `studentquestion` (`stdid`, `testid`, `qnid`, `answered`,  `stdanswer`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'answered', 'optiona'),
(1, 2, 1, 'answered', 'optiona');
```

Comment: You need to take it a step at a time.  It does not sound like you know what is going on at all.  There is too much wrong with what you say and expect.

Comment: You are using $_REQUEST and you got nothing? What are you expecting? Could you please echo the SQL statement to see what $_REQUEST stored?

Comment: It will store the following details
<?php echo $r3['questionsCorrect']; ?>
<?php echo $r3['percentScore']." %"; ?>

Comment: OK could you please show us the table structure and those php codes involved?

Comment: $SQL = "SELECT x.stdid, x.testid, x.questionsInTest, x.questionsCorrect, ROUND( 100.0 * x.questionsCorrect / x.questionsInTest ) AS percentScore FROM ( SELECT s.stdid, q.testid, COUNT(q.qnid) AS questionsInTest, SUM( IF(s.answered='answered' AND s.stdanswer=q.correctanswer, 1, 0 ) ) AS questionsCorrect FROM question AS q INNER JOIN studentquestion AS s ON q.testid = s.testid AND q.qnid = s.qnid WHERE q.testid=".$_REQUEST['testid']." GROUP BY s.stdid, q.testid ) AS X ORDER BY x.stdid, x.testid;"; echo $SQL; tell me what you get.

Comment: @AkiEru Hi, I have add my table on my quesiton...

Comment: @NavjotSingh Hi, it did have result come out but the result data is wrong...

Comment: So you want a script to compare the answer can calculate how many questions are correct and the marks instead of storing the data into database.

Comment: @AkiEru Yes...Indeed. And I does not wish to store the Where q.testid to  a fix value...I want it pass the value depends on the value that show in the link. For example when the testid in the link is 2, then the Where statement will change become something like WHERE q.testid='2'...
When the testid in the link is 3, then the Where statement will change become something like WHERE q.testid='3'

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement to get all student scores of your test.

```
SELECT sq.stdid, sq.testid, COUNT(*) AS correctAnswers, 
SUM(q.marks) AS studentScore, (SELECT SUM(marks) FROM question 
WHERE testid=$_REQUEST['testid']) AS totalScore 
FROM question q, studentquestion sq 
WHERE sq.testid=$_REQUEST['testid'] AND q.testid = sq.testid 
AND q.qnid = sq.qnid AND sq.answered = 'answered' 
AND q.correctanswer = sq.stdanswer GROUP BY sq.stdid;
```

You can create a PHP variable to calculate the percentage. For example:

```
$scorePercentage = $r3['studentScore'] / $r3['totalScore'] * 100;
```

or

```
$scorePercentage = $r3['studentScore'] .'/'. $r3['totalScore'];

// Output: echo $scorePercentage;
60
60/100
```

---

Use this SQL statement to get scorePercentage now:

```
SELECT sq.stdid, sq.testid, COUNT(*) AS correctAnswers, 
(SUM(q.marks) / (SELECT SUM(marks) FROM question WHERE testid=1) * 100) 
AS studentScorePercentage FROM question q, studentquestion sq 
WHERE sq.testid=$_REQUEST['testid'] AND q.testid = sq.testid AND q.qnid = sq.qnid 
AND sq.answered = 'answered' AND q.correctanswer = sq.stdanswer 
GROUP BY sq.stdid;
```

SQLFiddle with above results here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d47c/10

Comment: Hi, when I modify the code become like this 
                                $result3=executeQuery("SELECT sq.stdid, sq.testid, COUNT(*) AS correctAnswers, (SUM(q.marks) / (SELECT SUM(marks) FROM question WHERE testid=1) * 100) AS studentScorePercentage FROM question q, studentquestion sq WHERE sq.testid=".$_REQUEST['testid']." AND q.testid = sq.testid AND q.qnid = sq.qnid AND sq.answered = 'answered' AND q.correctanswer = sq.stdanswer GROUP BY sq.stdid;" );

The result will only pull out the stdid which is number 1 only

Comment: Check your studentquestion table to see if you only have 1 student ID. As you can see my fiddle I have two students. In your question you have only 1 student 2 two tests so I was actually modified your table structure.

Comment: Hi, I have 2 student in my databse that take the test, but it still only able to pull out 1 student result only...

Comment: It won't pull one student only, it will pull all students in the same test.
Check this fiddle (I didn't changed the SQL command, just added 2 students now it has 4 students in fiddle now): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cb97/1  If you use my SQL command can returned 1 student result, that should be your code's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change in rsltmng.php:

```
while($r1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
while($r3=mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
```

with:

```
while($r1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
while($r3=mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
```