# Fname and last name in mysql, error displaying

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem in my examination system. In the admin panel, in the results page displays the correct score but the firstname and the last name not. I dont know what to do.

Here is the code:

```
$result1=executeQuery("select s.nume_student,s.prenume_student,s.stdname,s.stdid, IFNULL((select sum(q.marks) from studentquestion as sq,question as q where q.qnid=sq.qnid and sq.testid=".$_REQUEST['testid']." and sq.stdid=st.stdid and sq.stdanswer=q.correctanswer),0) as om from studenttest as st, student as s where s.stdid=st.stdid and st.testid=".$_REQUEST['testid'].";" );


$result3=executeQuery("SELECT sq.stdid, sq.testid, COUNT(*) AS correctAnswers, SUM(q.marks) AS studentScore,(SELECT SUM(marks) FROM question WHERE testid=".$_REQUEST['testid'].") AS totalScore FROM question q, studentquestion sq WHERE sq.testid=".$_REQUEST['testid']." AND q.testid = sq.testid AND q.qnid = sq.qnid AND sq.answered = 'answered' AND q.correctanswer = sq.stdanswer GROUP BY sq.stdid");
```

without $result1 doesen't display anything

And here are the tables from database:

question table:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question` (
`testid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qnid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `question` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optiona` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionb` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optiond` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correctanswer` enum('optiona','optionb','optionc','optiond') DEFAULT NULL,
  `marks` float(3,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

studentquestion table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `studentquestion` (
  `stdid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `testid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qnid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `answered` enum('answered','unanswered','review') DEFAULT NULL,
  `stdanswer` enum('optiona','optionb','optionc','optiond') DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

student table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `stdid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `stdname` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stdpassword` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emailid` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contactno` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pincode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

student test table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `studenttest` (
  `stdid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `testid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `starttime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `endtime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `correctlyanswered` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('over','inprogress') DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and test table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `testid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `testname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `testdesc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `testdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `testtime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `subid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `testfrom` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `testto` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `totalquestions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attemptedstudents` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `testcode` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `tcid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I resolved the same problem of here:

[How to get sql WHERE statement auto update from localhost link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159052/how-to-get-sql-where-statement-auto-update-from-localhost-link/30275445#30275445)

but i'm stucked here with fname and last name.

Comment: First, fix the sql injection vulnerability

Comment: You might want to use the right fieldnames in your query. Also, if you're getting an error when you run your query, you should include it in your question.

Comment: I will fix with sql injection. I dont have any problem or error but i want to display the name of student next to result.

Answer (score 0):

If your second query returns the correct student ids, you can just change it to add student names:

```
SELECT s.lastname, s.firstname, e.* 
from 
students s join (
  ... your second query ... ) e
on s.stdid=e.stdid
```

you can change your join type depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but i resolved it like this:

```
SELECT ***s.fname, s.lname***, sq.stdid, sq.testid, COUNT(*) AS correctAnswers, 
   SUM(q.marks) AS studentScore,(SELECT SUM(marks) FROM question 
   WHERE testid=1) AS totalScore  
   FROM question q, studentquestion sq, ***student s*** 
   WHERE sq.testid=1 AND q.testid = sq.testid 
   AND q.qnid = sq.qnid AND sq.answered = 'answered' ***and sq.stdid=s.stdid***
   AND q.correctanswer = sq.stdanswer GROUP BY sq.stdid
```